# Columns information in Active Record Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, documentation

Is there a gem or plugin, that can generate a Comments with columns names above the class definition in Active Record model? I'm pretty sure that I've seen something like this, but can't find it anywhere:
Example:

```
# columns Defs
# name:string
# user_id:integer
# etc.
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I could as well write something like this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [annotate_models](http://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/) gem. [This](http://repo.pragprog.com/svn/Public/plugins/annotate_models/) is the version I once used, but can't tell if is still mantained.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all the model from app folder.

```
models = []
Dir.foreach("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models") do |model_path|
  if FileTest.directory?(model_path)
    next
  else
    filename = File.basename(model_path, '.rb')
    models << filename.camelize.constantize \
      if ["ActiveRecord::Base"].include?(filename.camelize.constantize.superclass.to_s)\
      && filename.camelize.constantize.table_exists?
  end
end
```

This will display all the columns with datatype.

```
for model in models
  puts model
  model.columns_hash.select {|column_name,column_type| puts column_name + ":" + column_type }
end
```

May be this will help you ??

Comment: Yeah, this would works, I would only has to put this in to rake script, add method to append comments with output to models.

Comment: @sparrow if my answer satisfy your question. please up vote and set it as your answer.

Comment: I would like to vote, cause I Like your answer, but I need 15 reputation to do so. I can't set it as an answer, cause I was looking for plugin

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of the [annotate_models](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/annotate_models) plugin.